# Qtranslate Shows Homepage if I translate an Existing Page

Tags: wordpress, translate, qtranslate

When I create a new page and translate it, it works great.

However, if I try to translate an existing page, which was created before I installed this plugin, it redirects or shows the homepage.

This is my debugging information

http://pastebin.com/YqZ4CzAm

Comment: What version is your Wordpress install and your qtranslate plugin?

Comment: Wordpress 3.4.1 and qtranslate the latest from the website @ScottBartell

Comment: Is your qtranslate version 2.5.31? You should be able to find this on the plugins page (/wp-admin/plugins.php).

Comment: @ScottBartell yes it is Version 2.5.31 | By Qian Qin | Visit plugin site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@SNaRe, I was having same issue couple of months back and after much efforts we dropped idea to go with qTranslate.

Finally we go with wpml plugin ([The WordPress Multilingual Plugin](http://wpml.org/)), and it was good choice.

P.S. I'm not promoting you to buy commercial plugin or I'm not representing WPML. I'm sharing my thoughts for betterment of the community. We've chosen WPML because our client was ready to pay otherwise we will search for other Free Plugin options.

Also, Here is a reason why we choose WPML instead qTranslate, posted on WordPress Codex site...

http://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress

some excerpt from same post...

> The free qTranslate plugin appears to be broken with WordPress v3.0,
>   but you can try [Multisite Language Switcher](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multisite-language-switcher/), [Multilingual Press](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multilingual-press/) or
>   purchase WPML.

Comment: I think this is what I am going to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you deactivate qTranslate for a moment, you can see what it does to your content in the HTML-view:

```
<!--:en-->
...code...
<!--:-->

<!--:ja-->
...code...
<!--:-->
```

This is how it works internally. Switch to the HTML-view in your editor and wrap your posts between these brackets. If you re-activate qTranslate afterwards, the post should not redirect any more.

Also check your qTranslate settings, if you took any redirection setting.

But be aware of the following: qTranslate destroys your clean WordPress posts permanently.

Comment: I tried everything. As you said I deactivated qTranslate and checked the content. It was same as you told. I wrapped my posts between these brackets and re-activated but nothing has changed. For qTranslate setting what may be the redirecting setting? I posted my debugging code. Please check it out if you can help. And I think we should consider that when I publish a new page, it works without problem. This problem persists only when I try to translate existing pages.

Comment: I was thinking maybe I should do something about database. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with other plugins that you have installed. Do you have any caching plugins installed? If so try disabling them and seeing if the problem still exists. Read [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-w3-total-cache-qtranslate-redirect-homepage-with-w3tc), it sounds somewhat similar to your problem.

Comment: I checked and not this one too.